# Replace Retrolambda with Android Studio 3.0 Java 8 built-in features

Tags: android, retrolambda, android-studio-3.0

In my project I'm using popular library **retrolambda**.
I've just downloaded new Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1.

I've updated my project to use new version of Gradle etc. And everything is OK.

What's new in Android Studio 3 is built in support for some Java8 features.
New AS3 is suggesting to remove retrolambda and use these features.

[image: Retrolambda warning]

I have removed retrolambda, Gradle build was successful but app is crashing with this error (in a place where there is lambda)

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method lambda$replace$2
```

I'm using RxJava2 in my project. I'm not sure this is related with it, but it looks like in my case built-in features for Java8 are not working. Maybe I need to set something "somewhere"?

My project settings[image]

My Gradle files

Root project

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        //classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
    }
```

App module

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

...



    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.+'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    //Support Library

(...)

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'

    /* RXJAVA2 */
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.VictorAlbertos:ReactiveCache:1.1.0-2.x'
    compile 'com.github.VictorAlbertos.Jolyglot:gson:0.0.3'


android {


    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my_app_id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

(...)

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }

        debugpro {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFile file('proguard-project.txt')
            proguardFile file('proguard-google-api-client.txt')
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFile file('proguard-project.txt')
            proguardFile file('proguard-google-api-client.txt')



        }
        releaseci {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFile file('proguard-project.txt')
            proguardFile file('proguard-google-api-client.txt')
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseci
        }


(...)

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }




}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

Comment: Show gradle files please

Comment: @TimCastelijns updated

Comment: can you show the code that crashes

Comment: Make sure you remove all the old code from the annotation preprocessor.   Theoretically a "clean" will do this, but I like to also do a: rm -rf build app/build to completely clean things out.

Comment: @JimAndreas I did clean, rebuild many times. Didn't work. I've got some additional logs that this could be related with ReactiveCache lib. I'm not sure this is it, I posted bug report on github.

Comment: @adek this rather sounds like a botch where the synthetic method for "replace" did not get created - either at compile time or maybe runtime.  Hard to say without seeing the code that crashes.

Comment: Same error with RxLocation lib! Have you able to solve this ?

Comment: @MohamedALOUANE unfortunatelly no.

Comment: @Mohamed ALOUANE See my answer and my comment on https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation/issues/37

Answer (score 4):

This is probably caused by a bug in the Gradle Java 8 language feature desugaring that is tracked in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62456849

`desugar` seems to blindly rename the synthetic methods in a class file if their name starts with `lambda$` (appending the owner class name) **regardless** of whether a reference to that method already exists in the bytecode (and that reference **doesn't** get renamed too).

When the code path hits such a reference at runtime the obvious result is a `NoSuchMethodError` because a method with that name doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Has this been solved coz. I am also facing this issue ? What is the solution to this desugaring problem ? @stefanzobel

Comment: @Akshay Mahajan Yes, this was fixed in Beta 1.

Comment: You mean to say `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'` @stefanzobel ?

Comment: @Akshay Mahajan Why use such an old version? The final release of AS 3.0 has been available for some time now. I use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`

Comment: I am using same `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` and AS 3.0, but no help. Am i missing something here ? @stefanzobel

Comment: @Akshay Mahajan Ask a new question (maybe linking to this one) and describe your problem in detail. It's impossible to judge from afar what your problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159541/discussion-between-akshay-mahajan-and-stefan-zobel).